# Ghostscript not writable

Tags: macos, homebrew, octave, ghostscript

Trying to install octave on a new Macbook, but keep running into problems using Homebrew. I am following directions here:
http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_MacOS_X

I run into the error:

```
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/ghostscript/9.14...
Error: Could not symlink share/ghostscript/Resource
/usr/local/share/ghostscript is not writable.
```

After entering:

```
sudo chown -R username:admin /usr/local/bin
brew link ghostscript
```

I still get the same error. How do I make ghostscript writable?

Answer (score 25):

Using this command worked for me:

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local/share/ghostscript
```

After that it was possible to create the symlink with:

```
brew link --overwrite ghostscript
```

Comment: In my case the directory was ```/usr/local/share/doc/ghostscript```

Answer (score 1):

Notice that /usr/local/share is outside /usr/local/bin.

Try `sudo chown -R username:admin /usr/local`.