# How to resolve Pandoc Error using kableExtra and taskScheduleR

Tags: r, pandoc, kable, kableextra

Current R Version: 3.4.1 64-bit

This error occurs when attempting to schedule a script that uses `kableExtra` to transform a dataframe into a html file and then save the html file locally. This is code where the error is occurring.

```
library(kableExtra)

df.html = df
kableExtra::kable(format = "html", escape = F) %>%
kableExtra::kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped","hover"), full_width = F)

df.html %>% kableExtra::save_kable(file = "Filelocation.html", self_contained = T)
```

This code is fine when running the script manually however it breaks when I run it through `rscript.exe`. The error being:

```
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 127
```

Are there any fixes for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34687030/pandoc-document-conversion-failed-with-error-127